# Strange Object Varibale Behaviour in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a really strange issue with JavaScript. I have a tile object that has a member variable type (and some other's but the issue is with type). If i set type to something besides the default value and log the object to console I get 2 different results depending on if I expand the object or not.

ie. this is what the console (tested in FireFox and Chrome) says for the un-expanded object:

```
Object { type: 4, subtype: 2, x: 0, y: 0, found: false }
```

this is what it says for the expanded object:

```
found: false​
subtype: 2​
type: 1​
x: 0​
y: 0
```

Notice that type changes values here.

This is the tile class:

```
class Tile {
    constructor(type, subtype) {
        this.type = type ? type : E_TileType.WALL;
        this.subtype = subtype ? subtype : E_TileSubtype.NONE;
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.found = false;
    }
}
```

This is my type Enum:

```
const E_TileType =
{
    BLANK: 0,
    WALL: 1,
    AIR: 3,
    PINCH: 4,
    COVER: 5
};
```

This is how I am currently trying to change these values:

```
var place = new Tile(E_TileType.PINCH, E_TileSubtype.Y_AXIS);
console.log(place);
```

I've also tried bypassing the constructor and setting the value as follows:

```
var place = new Tile();
place.type = E_TileType.PINCH;
console.log(place);
```

No matter what I do I always seem to get the same weird double value behaviour. I have never seen this happen before and I'm at a loss from where to go from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you changing the object after the console.log? The value shown in unexpanded console.log is the value at the moment it was logged. Once you expand it, you will see the current value of the object properties.

Comment: On Firefox, and that didn't happen for me.

Comment: what is E_TileSubtype

Comment: There's a bit too much explanation interspersed with the code, so it's hard to put this together into an [mcve]. Can you show a stack snippet that we can press a button and see the misbehavior? Thanks.

Comment: @EliasSoares Really? I didn't know the console worked like that. I've gone over my code again and it turns out that in one of my if's was setting the type instead of checking it. Thank you, knowing that behaviour made it much easier to find the problem!

Comment: To everyone else who responded, thank you very much it seems my problem was just a silly typo combined with a misunderstanding of how the console displays data.